# Fetching unique record in Xsl and using the values in transformed XML

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, transformation

I have an input XML similar to below structure:

```
<request>
  <X>
    <Y>
        ...
        <Cid>1</Cid>
        <Sid>2</Sid>
        <Pid>
            <A1>
                ..
            </A1>
        </Pid>
    </Y>
  </X>
</request>
<request>
  <X>
    <Y>
        ...
        <Cid>1</Cid>
        <Sid>3</Sid>
        <Pid>
            <A1>
                ..
            </A1>
        </Pid>
    </Y>
  </X>
</request>
<request>
  <X>
    <Y>
        ...
        <Cid>1</Cid>
        <Sid>2</Sid>
        <Pid>
            <A1>
                ..
            </A1>
        </Pid>
    </Y>
  </X>
</request>
<request>
  <X>
    <Y>
        ...
        <Cid>2</Cid>
        <Sid>2</Sid>
        <Pid>
            <A1>
                ..
            </A1>
        </Pid>
    </Y>
  </X>
</request>
```

I have to extract few unique Id combination of [Cid and Sid] at top of transformed XML. Rest of the data(fetched from Pid, A1,Y etc.) will be transformed and put under otherDtls node which comes after all Id created. Output would be something like below:

```
<Id>
        <Id1>2</Id1>
        <Id2>1</Id2>
</Id>
<Id>
        <Id1>3</Id1>
        <Id2>1</Id2>
</Id>
<Id>
        <Id1>2</Id1>
        <Id2>2</Id2>
</Id>
<otherDtls>
    .....
<otherDtls>
```

Note that [Cid value '1' AND Sid value '2'] combination were duplicate hence it appeared only once in transformed XML.
Also, please note Cid value goes in Id2 and Sid value goes in Id1. I am not able to find any working solution to extract unique Id combination of [Cid and Sid] and get the values to change the tag name and print at top.

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

It is a [grouping problem](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.xml), use a grouping key that concatenates `Cid` and `Sid` e.g. `<xsl:key name="group" match="Y" use="concat(Cid, '|', Sid)"/>`.

Comment: You are assuming XSLT 1.0.